# How do I change the numbering system of table captions?

Tags: tables, formatting, numbering, captions

Normally when a table is captioned, it comes out as "Table 1: Blah blah...", but I want to change it to "TABLE I. Blah blah..." How do I do that? So far, I've figured out how to change the title and period, but not the number to a roman numeral:

```
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=TABLE}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=TABLE}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    A table
    \caption{My table}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sean Glad it helped. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem. For details refer [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)